# Reading Twitter streaming data in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to read streaming Twitter data in Azure Databricks using pyspark but I do not know how to do this? I found several links on internet but all of them requires hostid or IP address of my local machine but as I want to do this on cloud is there any way or other code to do so?

https://towardsdatascience.com/sentiment-analysis-on-streaming-twitter-data-using-spark-structured-streaming-python-fc873684bfe3
Above link shows how to read on local machine.

Thanks,
Surbhi

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `socket.gethostname()` and it should also work .